# What events do I need to implement if I want a method to trigger when a DataGridView is changed?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm not familiar with DataGridViews, but I need to work with one in this case.
Basically, I have a method I want to call anytime the state of the DataGridView is changed in ANY way (cells added, removed, changed, etc). There seem to be many events, but I'm not sure which ones are relevant (I'm assuming I'll use more that one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some key methods to think about, some already mentioned and some additional:

- **RowsAdded**: Triggered by user- or programmatic-added rows.
- **RowsRemoved**: Triggered by user- or programmatic-removed rows.
- **ColumnAdded**: Triggered by user- or programmatic-added column. (If applicable.)
- **ColumnRemoved**: Triggered by user- or programmatic-removed column. (If applicable.)
- **CellValueChanged**: Triggered when the value of a cell changes.

And if you are using a `DataSource`:

- **DataSourceChanged**: Triggered when a new source is set.

This is strictly assuming your definition of "*changed*" does not include resize events of the `DataGridView`, its columns, or its rows nor any other formatting alteration.  If you refer only to a change in the number of cells and any change in any single value, these suggestions should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UserDeletedRow or RowsRemoved event for removing; also UserAddedRow or RowsAdded event for adding new row; 
For checking cells you can use CellEndEdit event;